# Mejor estrategia para subir documentos al servidor y no entren en conflicto por el nombre

Tags: php

Quiero subir varios documentos al servidor, .jpg, .pgn, .doc, .pdf

Para lo anterior tengo lo siguiente:

HTML:

```
   <body>    
        <form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
           <input type="file" name="foto">
           <input type="submit" value="upload">
        </form>
    </body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $carpeta="documentos/";
    opendir($carpeta);
    $destino=$carpeta.$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    copy($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$destino);
    echo 'Archivo subido OK <br>';
    $nombre=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
    echo "<img src=\"documentos/$nombre\"><br>";
    echo $_FILE['foto']['name'];
?>
```

Pero al directorio donde se almacenan los documentos subidos, se pueden subir documentos por distintos usuarios, que pueden subir documentos con los mismos nombres, luego, para que no entren en conflicto entre ellos, podría:

1) Crear tantas carpetas(directorios) en el servidor como usuarios que van a usar el sistema; aproximadamente unas 40 carpetas, pero lo anterior no garantiza que un mismo usuario pueda subir dos veces el mismo documento con el mismo nombre.

2) A través de un secuencial, obtenido de la BD, que permita agregar este secuencial al nombre del archivo subido. Esto conlleva a mantener este secuencial en la BD, pero podría ocurrir que en algún momento dos usuarios estén haciendo la consulta a la BD del siguiente secuencial y se asigne el mismo siguiente número, con lo cual si los nombres son iguales, podrían ser iguales "nombre+sec".

3) Que cuando se vaya a subir el archivo al servidor, que se le agregue la fecha actual (dd-mm-aaaa hh:mm:ss o código numérico que la represente) al nombre del archivo, pero eventualmente, dos usuarios en máquinas distintas podrían subir un documento con el mismo nombre en el mismo momento y el "nombre+time" podrían ser iguales.

4) Que cuando se suba el archivo, se agregue al nombre del archivo, el nombre del usuario (SESSION), más la fecha actual (dd-mm-aaaa hh:mm:ss o código numérico que la represente).

Yo entiendo que la opción 4 podría ser la más indicada, pero no sé si hay otras más eficientes.

Gracias.

Agrego más antecedentes para que se entienda la casuística:

El usuario A entra a la aplicación web y sube el documento "info.pdf". En paralelo, un usuario B que ingresó al sistema web en otro equipo, sube al mismo tiempo que el usuario A, el documento "info.pdf". Como ambos tienen el mismo nombre, es que consulto cuál sería la mejor estrategia a implementar para que dichos archivos queden en un directorio en el servidor, asociados en la BD a los usuarios que lo subieron y que después en otro momento, cada usuario pueda recuperar sus documentos que subió.

Cuál sería la forma de implementar en forma más eficiente este tema? Gracias.

Comment: Y porque no usar el nombre temporal con el que viene, dejarlo por ese nombre y solo poner en la DB el nombre real? asi te olvidas de todas estas ideas... Un GUID seria la solucion ideal... y ademas si, abre por meses o añomes o algo asi para no sobrecargar una sola carpeta con todos los archivos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar esto, usando la función uniqid y time para obtener un nombre aleatorio para tu archivo.
[Manual de uniqid() de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php) y [Manual de time() de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.time.php)

```
<?php
        $carpeta="documentos/";
        opendir($carpeta);
        $nombre_archivo = time() . uniqid() . '.' . pathinfo($_FILES['foto']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $destino = $carpeta . $nombre_archivo;
        copy($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],$destino);
        echo 'Archivo subido OK <br>';
        $nombre = $nombre_archivo;
        echo "<img src=\"documentos/$nombre\"><br>";
        echo $nombre;
    ?>
```

Otro dato importante es que puedes aprovechar para organizar esa información en carpetas cuyo nombre será el id del usuario, por ejemplo /documentos/usuario1234/archivos/archivo.ext

de este modo podrás tener todo organizado y en un futuro dar un servicio de backups donde el orden te libre de muchos dolores de cabeza en el futuro, cabe recalcar que puse una carpeta que se llama archivos, porque así podrías otra carpeta donde se contenga información como fotos de perfil,audios del perfil, etc; y crearías otra carpeta con el nombre "medios" por ejemplo o "media", como por ejemplo: /documentos/usuario1234/media/profile-pic1.jpg .

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo el propósito de lo que estás haciendo pero creo que lo más sencillo si no tienes que recuperar los archivos, es que le hagas un pequeño hash, el nombre del archivo va a ser más grande pero te aseguras que nunca vas a tener dos nombres iguales (O que si los tienes, va a ser el mismo archivo, por lo que evitas tener dos copias exactamente iguales.)

Por otro lado, si quieres hacerlo secuencial con la base de datos podrías hacerlo de una forma poco elegante pero funcional, y es crearte una tabla auxiliar que sea algo como ConsultarSecuencia y que tenga una única columna de tipo bool con único dato que en principio este a "true".

Y en tu código PHP haces la siguiente query

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$ sql = "UPDATE ConsultarSecuencia SET columna = false WHERE columna = true;";
do{
    $mysqli->query($sql);
while($mysqli->affected_rows);

//Código para consultar la secuencia en la base de datos

$ sql = "UPDATE ConsultarSecuencia SET columna = true WHERE columna = false;";
$mysqli->query($sql);
$mysqli->close();
```

Siendo columna el nombre que le hayas puesto a la única columna de la tabla.

De esta manera sabrás que sólo sólo hay un proceso leyendo de la tabla de secuencias de la base de datos.

Esto es así, porque mientras que las lecturas en una tabla no son atómicas, las escrituras sí lo son para asegurar la integridad. 
De esta manera se aseguras que jamás vas a tener dos archivos iguales, por contra, no vas a saber qué usuario los ha subido.

Sin embargo este sistema es bastante burdo y lento, pues hay varias llamadas a la base de datos (Con el tiempo que esto conlleva).

Otra opción posible es que añadieses a cada usuario una campo en la base de datos con el número de archivos subidos hasta el momento y que se actualice con cada archivo que suba.
Esta manera es mucho más elegante.

Si esto no te parece adecuado, creo que tu opción 4 sería la más rápida en términos de eficiencia.

Por otro lado, yo usaría la función [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php) de php ya que te devuelve un array con el número de segundos transcurridos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 y con el número de microsegundos del segundo actual, con lo que, que coincida el número de microsegundos es prácticamente  imposible.